# auto-complete form and send with jsoup

Tags: jsoup

I have a problem to sending text fields and complete a form. I use jsoup for a POST sending. My code is...

```
   Response response = Jsoup.connect(url)
              .ignoreContentType(true) 
              .userAgent("Mozilla")
              .referrer(url)
              .followRedirects(true)
              .data("TextNome", "XXX")
              .data("TextCognome", "YYY")
              .data("TextP_IVA", "IVA12345678910")
              .data("TextCodice", "COD$12345678910X")
              .method(Method.POST)
              .execute();
```

The url is [click](http://ftsoft81.altervista.org/modulo_1/code/modulo_1.php)
Where am I wrong? The text fields are all mandatory. From the log it seems that the fields are not set.

Answer (score 0):

The form you want to submit has many elements of type "hidden input", such as:

> < input type="hidden" name="sfm_form_submitted" value="yes">

You should add this hidden fields to your POST request (look at the HTML source code to discover them), then it should work